# jquery fadeTo after timeout

Tags: jquery, fadeto

Our div #logo is set to 0.8 opacity via css:

```
background:rgba(50,50,50,0.8)
```

After a delay, #logo is faded to 0.4 and #main-navigation is animated:

```
$("#main-navigation").delay(7000).slideUp(1000);
$("#logo").delay(7000).fadeTo(1000,0.4);
```

When the mouse is moved, #logo is faded to 0.99 and #main-navigation is animated again:

```
var c;
$(document).on('mousemove',function() {        
$("#logo").fadeTo(1000,0.99);
$("#main-navigation").slideDown(1000);
....
```

Then a timer is set and #logo helpshould be faded back to 0.4 and #main-navigation is animated one final time:

```
....
clearTimeout(c);
c= setTimeout(function(){
$("#logo").fadeTo(1000,0.4);
$("#main-navigation").slideUp(1000);
}, 2000);
});
```

Everything works fine EXCEPT for fading #logo back to 0.4.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

```
$("#logo").stop().fadeTo(1000,0.4);
```

If that's not working, please provide a http://www.jsfiddle.net with your relevant code

---

## .stop()

> **.stop( [clearQueue ] [, jumpToEnd ] )** Returns: jQuery
>
> **Description:** Stop the currently-running animation on the matched
> elements.